# Getting seconds from a timestamp in POSIXct using an origin different than Jan 1, 1970 in R

Tags: r

This might look like a duplicate question but I haven't been able to find the correct answer. I am processing some data in R and I want to store timestamp (one of the variables) as seconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1960 instead of default in R which is Jan 1, 1970. I am doing this because my aim is to merge this data set with a SAS data set which also has the timestamp column and the defalt in SAS is Jan 1, 1960. Here is what I am trying to accomplish-

```
x <- "2017/04/11 10:32"
x <- as.POSIXct(x, format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M", origin="1960-01-01", tz="UTC")
x <- as.numeric(x)
```

This gives me x = 1491906720 which is wrong because it should be 1807525920 according to SAS. I tried going also backwards as shown below and got the correct result.

```
x <- 1807525920
x <- as.POSIXct(x, origin="1960-01-01", tz="UTC")
```

which gave me x = "2014-04-11 10:32:00" which is correct. I am not sure where I am wrong. This is probably a very silly thing but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`origin` is useful for importing numeric dates (typically generated by other programs which may be using a different origin than R). That explains why you got expected output the second time. Since you are converting string to POSIXct at first, `origin` is not doing anything there. Use `difftime` to obtain the interval between `x` and whatever other date you want.

```
x = "2017/04/11 10:32"
as.numeric(difftime(time1 = as.POSIXct(x, tz = "UTC"),
                    time2 = as.POSIXct("1960-01-01", tz = "UTC"),
                    units = "secs"))
#[1] 1807525920
```